# Nginx query keyword matching in location

Tags: nginx

I have the following

```
location ~ "/foo/(.+)\.\w{3}$" {
  alias /srv/DM/pictures/store/$1;
}
```

That does exactly what I want, with one small exception. If there is a *query keyword* appended to the location I want it to not-match:

```
MATCH: http://foo/bar.jpg
NO: http://foo/bar.jpg?s_thumb
NO: http://foo/bar.jpg?large_thumb
```

Any ideas on how to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a ***minimal understanding of the problem being solved***. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. [See How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as locations will only match against the URI without query parameters. You'll need to use an if inside the location along with http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24arg_PARAMETER

```
if ($is_args) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I finally got working. You can't simply place the [`alias`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) inside of the `if` statement. But, you can use an [*internal*](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal) redirect

```
server {

  ...;

  location /_image {
    internal;
    alias /srv/DM/pictures/store/;
  }

  location / {

    ...;

    if ( $args = '' ) {
      rewrite "/image/(.*)\.\w{3}$" /_image/$1 last;
    }

    ...;

}
```